# Make a <ul> tag display on the same line as text

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a `<ul>` tag display inline with a line of text. here's the HTML.

```
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="449" value="Whats that?" class="checkbox"><label for="449">Whats that?</label>
  <ul class="449">
    <li>{...removed...}</li>
    <li>{...removed...}</li>
    <li>{...removed...}</li>
    <li>{...removed...}</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

What it renders as now is this:

```
Whats that?
  Li element
  Li element
  Li element
  Li element
```

But I want it to render like this:

```
Whats that? Li element
            Li element
            Li element
            Li element
```

What CSS rules do i need to put into that `<ul>`? And nevermind that class name, it's for zany javascript purposes. Thank you!

Comment: Put the INPUT in the LABEL. Then float the LABEL left.

Comment: I think you need to use each of element as a column (INPUT and UL) and use float/margin to get it right (but just speculating here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Float them:

```
p, ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

<p>Whats that?</p>
<ul>
    <li>Li element</li>
    <li>Li element</li>
    <li>Li element</li>
    <li>Li element</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what if I wanted to center these within a div?

Answer (score 3):

```
ul.449{
 display: inline-block;   
}
```

Will get it inline. The vertical alignment is a bit weird.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely gets it inline... Any suggestions on fixing that vertical align? Possibly a rule in the parent li tag?

Comment: IE doesn't support inline-block on UL. Also, no browser accepts stylings where the class name starts with a number.

Comment: IE isn't a concern in this project. Just needs to work for Gecko and Webkit. Also, i'll probably style this UL through a parent rather than with the class directly. Like I said before, the class name isn't for style; it's for javascript.

Comment: The closest (not perfect) way to get the tops to line up is adding `vertical-align:top` to your inline-block rule.

Comment: @Madison Williams Right. I'm just saying that any solution that uses `ul.449` as the selector won't work. I tried it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest `ul.449 { display:inline-table}` but it will support ie8+. Another solution with cross browser support I suppose could be to `float:left;` all elements (`input`, `label`, `ul`) and add `margin:0;` the `ul`

First approach: http://jsbin.com/axako3/2

Second approach: http://jsbin.com/axako3/3